# Files from ActiveStorage not displaying with "Missing Template" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Rails v5.2.1; Files are uploaded to a private AWS bucket using `DirectUpload`, but I don't think that's my issue.

I have a User model which contains `has_one_attached :avatar`. The image is uploaded without issue; I see it in my bucket & in the ActiveStorage tables in my DB.

I later try to display the uploaded avatar like this:

```
<%= image_tag url_for(current_user.avatar) %>
(I've also tried this):
<img src="<%= url_for(current_user.avatar) -%>" />
```

This generates a URL, something like `http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/[a hash, I assume]/[my file name].png`

However... no image is displayed. If I try to open the image in a new tab, I get a "Template Is Missing" error page.

```
Missing template /application with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:png], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/matt/projects/project/app/views" * "/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/kaminari-core-1.1.1/app/views" * "/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/devise-4.4.3/app/views"

Extracted source:

def index
  render template: 'application'
end
```

Now... I definitely have an `application.html` template, but this seems to be looking for an `application.png` template, which doesn't seem right. What am I missing?

Comment: i dunno exactly what it could be, but my guess aws url is private and throws an error cause of that.

Comment: Is there a way to get Rails to tell me where it's actually going?

Comment: can u check this `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(current_user.avatar, only_path: true)` like this, see what exactly URL generates for u

Comment: I also discovered `user.avatar.service_url`, which seems to give me the direct link to AWS... Going to use that unless I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Does it show the image now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### View

```
<%= image_tag url_for(current_user.avatar_url) %>
```

#### User model

```
#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    #...
    def avatar_url
      if self.avatar.attached?
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.avatar, only_path: true)
        #or
        self.avatar.service_url
      else
        nil
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: The `rails_blob_path` part doesn't work, but the `service_url` part does, so good enough for my purposes!

Comment: alright, updating my post then. On my case, i used `rails_blob_path`.